# JS: conditional image-link based on screeen width

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

I want to disable the link below when screen-width < (say) 1080 pix. So I need some JS to do the job, and I'm completely new to JS.

Simplified:

```
    IF SCREEN-WIDTH<1080 THEN
        <a href="test01.jpg" target=_blank;>
             <img src="test01.jpg" width="100%" height=auto> 
        </a>
    ELSE
        <img src="test01.jpg" width="100%" height=auto> // NO LINK
```

brgds

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Comment: Hiding items based on screen size can be done with CSS and frameworks like bootstrap. The [Hiding elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) . Adding `class="d-lg-none"` to a `div` hides it on large screens, while `d-lg-block` would display it on large screens. `d-none d-lg-block` will hide it by default, except for large screens. Effectively, it will hide the `div` on screens smaller than `lg`. The various sizes are [described here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)